# Oracle data paging optimization

Tags: performance, oracle, pagination

```
select * from (
 select t_tmp_a.*, rownum t_tmp_id from (
 select  t.*, i.counts  
 from table1 t, (select id, count(id) counts from table2 group by id) i
 where t.id=i.id and t.kindid in (0,1,3) order by t.id desc
) t_tmp_a where rownum <= 20) t_tmp_b where t_tmp_id >= 11;
```

table1 and table2 have more then 2 million data per table, when execute this query need 18s , before this query execute we should calculation total count need about 7s, so it spends more than 25s， any idea to optimiza it?

Comment: Probablly an  http://dba.stackexchange.com/ issue.

Comment: @Mat, Sorry, I have post this question to that site.

Comment: @Mat thanks for your warning.. I have no idea about flag feature since now.

Comment: @Mat, thank you of your reminder, I have done like you said.

Comment: Really not sure why people have decided this is off-topic.  This is a question which is addressable through programming techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is usually a mechanism for displaying a result to a human being.  No human being wants to read two million rows of data.

So if this query is indeed presenting rows to a real person then what you need to address is reducing the size of the whole result to something which is human-sized.  So you need to apply additional filters in the database and return a focused result set.  Not only will your users thank you, so will your network administrator.

On the other hand, if the intended recipient of this data deluge is a computer or other mechanical device then just give it the whole thing.  Machines mostly don't care about pages, or if they do (spreadsheets, printers, etc) they have built-in sub-routines to handle pagination for us.

---

So that leaves us with the problem that your original query takes a long time to execute.  Without any explain plan or statistics (how many rows in `table1` fit the search criteria?  how restricting are those values for `kindid`?) it is hard to solve this.

> "kindid is a type which only have three choose(0,1,3)"

Fnord.  If KINDID can only have *three* choices what is the point of using it in the WHERE clause?

In fact removing it from the WHERE clause may dramatically improve the performance of your query.  Unless you have gathered histograms for that column Oracle will assume that `in (0,1,3)` is somehow going to restrict the result set; whereas that is only going to be true if the majority of rows have a NULL in that column.  If that is the case it would be better to use `kindid is not null`.

Comment: yes, I agree, The result display to the human being, maybe I should add default time filter at first access , if the user add their filters I should desert default filter, If I use the right way?

Comment: table1 is about two million rows, too, will have more in the future, kindid is a type which only have three choose(0,1,3). @APC